# how to access portable usb storage device from android code?

Tags: android, storage, portability

Currently I am working on a project which needs the capability to access the portable usb storage device connecting to an android device using OTG cable. How can I access the connected storage device in android code? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android detect usb storage for kitkat (4.4)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208297/android-detect-usb-storage-for-kitkat-4-4)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208297/android-detect-usb-storage-for-kitkat-4-4/. I posted solutions for both pre-6.0 and 6.0/above.